# How to encrypt localdb mdf file without thirdParty tool?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have used SQL server 2017 local db. I created one windows application and how to protect the mdf file. How to encrypt localdb MDF file without third party tool?

Comment: I'd expect native SQL Server encryption to work, but I don't use local databases here, and Microsoft has surprised me before. See [SQL Server Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/sql-server-encryption?view=sql-server-2017). FWIW, "encrypting the database" and "encrypting the mdf file" are not quite the same thing.

Comment: Who are you trying to protect the data from -- a curious end user opening the database outside of your application, or someone who yanked out the harddisk and is now trying to read an offline copy? The latter can be protected against with BitLocker or Always Encrypted, but the former requires that you do your own encrypting (and can always be bypassed by a sufficiently savvy user, since they can do anything your application can do).

Answer (score 0):

All editions of SQL server 2017 have an Always Encrypted feature that you can use to encrypt specific data but may require some modifications to the application.  The enterprise version of SQL Server 2017 has a Transparent Data Encryption feature that makes the process a little more seamless.

You can read more about the Always Encrypted feature here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: but it's work in the Express Enterprise Edition of SQL Server but i used only localdatabase. And also i need full mdf file with encryption.

Comment: "SQL Server Express LocalDB is a lightweight version of Express that has all of its programmability features, runs in user mode and has a fast, zero-configuration installation and a short list of prerequisites."  Without third party tools or writing your own encryption/decryption for the MDF , you are not going to be able to encrypt the MDF.  The best that you'll be able to do is encypt all the data that is IN the MDF.

Comment: I am getting this error "Transparent Data Encryption is not available in the edition of this SQL Server instance."

Comment: Yeah, your using localdb, not the enterprise version.  Your only option is encrypting the data in the database. Your not going to be able to do the entire file unless you do it manually.  Essentially you'll have to decrypt the db, open the connection, do your crud operation, close the connection and re-encrypt the database.  You can do that with the built cryptography objects in .Net, but if someone copies your DB or crashes your app while the db is open, they just defeated your intent.

Comment: @GaryStewart
Can you please give me simple steps for your encryption proposal?